# How to mute sound alert when a key is not recognized?

Tags: macos, macbook-pro, mac

I'm pressing <kbd>F16</kbd>and it's not bound to anything and it's making a sound, like a bip alerting me that the command is not found. How can I mute this sound?

Answer (score 1):

You can completely disable alert sounds. If it's right for you, do it this way :

1. Go to System Preferences.app > Sound > Sound Effects
2. Mute the Alert Volume using the slider[image]